# Xna Windows Phone 7 Saving Game Data

Tags: xna

Im trying to find out how to save highscore data to the isolated storage on windows phone. I have searched numerous things and have found nothing working. Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer was taken from this MSDN entry:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604992.aspx

> XNA Game Studio 4.0 Refresh does not provide access to writeable
>   storage on Windows Phone. To access such storage, you'll need to use
>   classes from the System.IO.IsolatedStorage namespace.
>
> For Windows Phone projects, Visual Studio automatically adds the
>   assembly containing System.IO.IsolatedStorage to your project. There
>   is no need to add any additional references to your project.

Examples for writing data to the Isolated storage:

```
protected override void OnExiting(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
        {
            // Save the game state (in this case, the high score).
            IsolatedStorageFile savegameStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

            // open isolated storage, and write the savefile.
            IsolatedStorageFileStream fs = null;
            using (fs = savegameStorage.CreateFile(SAVEFILENAME))
            {
                if (fs != null)
                {
                    // just overwrite the existing info for this example.
                    byte[] bytes = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(highScore);
                    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
            }

            base.OnExiting(sender, args);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, how could i find the on exiting event in xna @Nahuell.

Comment: I cannot try it on my machine now as I have some problems with the WP emulator, but the onExiting method is part of the game class, you should have no problem adding it to your Game1 class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.onexiting(v=XNAGameStudio.40).aspx

If that doesn't work, you can add the code to the UnloadContent method as well, which is the executed before exiting the game.

Comment: @user3453481
Update, I was able to do this on a Windows Game project and I can guarantee that you can add the method to the Game1 class.

Simply type protected override (space) and all methods that can be overridden will be shown to you.

protected override void OnExiting(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            base.OnExiting(sender, args);
        }

Comment: Its not really working. It's failing to open the file. What does the fileName have to be (format). @Nahuell.

Comment: The format should be <filename>.<extension> (example.txt, example.xml) if I'm not wrong. What error are you getting? Are you saving inside an additional directory? @user3453481